# Underscore at end of URLs with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I type "go" in Google Chrome 41, I get
"google.com_/" as a suggestion:

[image]

This happens for other websites, too. Does anybody have an idea why this happens and how I can remove those suggestions?

(I certainly never typed it)

Comment: This seems to only happen for me on sites where I have a search keyword setup.

Comment: This still happens to me. ebay where I use tab search keeps creating underscores on the url.

Answer (score 45):

I've had the same issue with the underscore after urls in Chrome's search suggestion box. I'm not sure what causes it, but to remove them start typing the URL that has the issue in the URL box. When the suggestion shows up, press the down arrow on the keyboard to select it and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>. For macOS users <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: it works! I still wonder what actually causes this.

Comment: Fn + Shift + Delete for Mac OS

Comment: OMG! Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively you can also click the small 'x' on the right side of the suggestion.

Comment: You might have to do it more than once.

Comment: clicking on the small X next to the suggestion does nothing for me.. it still comes up everytime. I'm on chromeos, on chrome, how is this so Buggy, Google?!?

Comment: any idea what the keyboard shortcut to remove these items is in chromeos?

Answer (score 13):

I found this SE question before I found the following article.  Figured I'd update here in case anyone else has the same issue.

It seems there is (was?) a bug in Chrome with how search URL's are harvested.  You have to manually clean up your search engines in Chrome's settings.

[How to fix trailing underscores at the end of URLs in Chrome](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/fix-trailing-underscores-at-the-end-of-urls-chrome/).

Comment: Even after manually cleaning up search engines, I still had to follow the steps listed by @Bag_of_sunshine to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Daniel - I think that keeps more from showing up, but you still need to clean up the mess they made.